# @objc requirement for Swift 3?

Tags: objective-c, swift, swift3, mkmapview

Any idea why i my Swift 3 iOS app, this

```
@objc(mapView:rendererForOverlay:) func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
```

triggers,
but if I replace above statement with this

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
```

does not trigger.

Comment: No, I meant if i replace the top statement with below, it stops working.

Comment: Edited to clarify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even matt's answer is correct I want to explain the reason for the underscore.

Why do you need the underscore?

Short answer: Because this is the declaration of the method:

```
 optional func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, 
      rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer
```

https://developer.apple.com/reference/mapkit/mkmapviewdelegate/1452203-mapview

Long answer:

tl;dr: You need it to delete a leading parameter name for the first parameter in Swift 3.0.

To understand that you have to know the whole story:

Objective-C has akin of named arguments: The whole method declaration including the parts ahead of a parameter declaration is a part of the method identifier. Having the method …:

```
- (MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView 
        rendererForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay;
```

… this means, that the identifier of the method (selector) is `mapView:renderForOverlay:`. This system was simple and in use for a long time. It was powerful, because it makes method overloading unnecessary.

According to Swift's design principle, to make working and simple things that complex that it is impossible to say, whether they are working, they did some tricky hacks:

Swift has akin of translation mechanism from Objective-C selectors to Swift function and parameter identifiers. They found a great solution in Swift 1.2(?), that makes things easier by far. Later they recognized, that the great and easy solution is confusing and they offered a new solution in Swift 2.0 which is greater and easier by far. Later they recognized, that the greater and easier solution is confusing and they offered a new-new solution in Swift 3.0, which is greater-greater by far-far.

While in Swift < 3.0 the first (external) parameter name defaults to nothing (because the first part of the selector becomes the function name) this rule does not apply anymore and you have to specify that. The underscore simply says, that there is no external name. So your method name is translated correctly to Objective-C's selector.

It takes the function name `mapView` adds no external name because of the `_`, so it is `mapView:`. And then it adds the next external parameter name `renderFor`, which leads to `mapView:renderFor`, then the parameter name `overlay`, capitalize it to `Overlay`, which leads to `mapView:renderForOverlay:` – the correct selector.

Quite easy, quite simple. Another feature that makes things in Swift great and easy. Much easier as in Objective-C

Answer (score 1):

One obvious problem is that, in Swift 3, this is not the correct signature:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, 
    rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
```

The [correct signature](https://developer.apple.com/reference/mapkit/mkmapviewdelegate/1452203-mapview) is:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, 
    rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
```

Notice the difference (the "underscore").

Another possible problem happens if your code is not inside a class or extension declaration that *explicitly* declares conformance to MKMapViewDelegate. Swift 3 is very choosy about this. (You did not show enough context for me to know if you're getting that part right.)

The `@objc` declaration works around both problems by explicitly bridging this function to Objective-C. But if you do it right on both counts, Swift will do the bridging for you and the `@objc` will not be needed.

Comment: what does _ signify ?

Comment: That is the "underscore" that I am talking about. It is essential. Insert it as I have shown, and your code will be called.